# Why can't I link certain portals after creating a field?

Tags: ingress

So I noticed that after I created a pretty big field in Syracuse University I was unable to link certain portals. More specifically, Bird Library portal. I do have Bird Library keys, so I'm not sure why I can't link these :| Are my fields/links in the way?

[image: Problem portal]

Comment: Some screenshots would likely be helpful in answering that question.

Comment: @kotekzot I've added a screenshot, sorry t.t

Comment: More than likely, fields/links are in the way. I see a nice one just to the left of the highlighted portal, and that would block pretty much every portal except the one to the bottom right, and the top left on that same field.

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer uncovering some unclear linking mechanics, be sure to check it out! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, when a portal cannot be linked, there are two possibilities:

1) the portal is out of reach. This should not be the case, since, with the configuration you've showed, you would have had range problems only with L1 portals;

2) as you correctly said, there are fields and links in the way. It's impossible to cross two links, even if they are from your own faction. With the field configuration you've created, the only portals that can be linked to the Bird Library are these (one is under the word "resonators"):

[image]

Creating a link from these portals, if their level is high enough, should give you no problem. The rest is blocked by the field mantained by those two same portals. That's why, as a general rule, you should try to make your links the shortest possible: you always risk to block the creation of links/fields for you or your fellow agents.

Comment: Remember another thing:
You can throw links from one that is in the outside of the field, to another that is inside. BUT, not from inside to the outside:
Portal A (inside), Potal B(outside)

A--->B NOO
B--->A YES!

Just remember it whe u want to create lot of fields in a zone.
Recomendation: create the fields in the "center" and go to the biggest one. (From inside to outside)

Comment: @Shudy Wait, how does that work? If I have a portal outside of a field and I try to link it to a portal that's inside a field, wouldn't my link have to go through the link that forms the field?

Comment: @Shelby.S Yes, it would have to, but it can't. Link may not cross each other.

Answer (score 10):

@Shelby. S
Example :

You have the fields created by some reason in this form

Black links has been created and you have 3 fields.

If you try to create a link from some portal that is inside from one to is outside --> is not possible.

If you try to create a link from some portal that is outside from one to is inside --> is possible.

You CANT cross a link with another one.

In this image I made, now you have 3 fields.
If you throw a link from bottom left portal, to the portal in the center, you create 2 fields more, because you "cut" in a half another field.

[image]

Comment: This is great answer which covers those weird scenarios when you think you should be able to link but you are not, but then in the end you are .. Should be accepted instead.

Answer (score 5):

The linkability is actually **very straightforward**, once you understand a few **simple** rules.

Prerequisites:

- Source portal must be fully deployed
- Destination portal must be fully deployed
- A portal can have maximum <del>7</del> 8 outgoing links. Incoming links are not capped.

Then:

1. The source portal can't be **under** a field. (Though the destination portal can.)
2. The destination portal must be within a range. (The range can be extended using LinkAmps.)
3. There must not be any crossing links on the link path.

Here is an example of what a portal **under** a field looks like and what doesn't.

- **Red portals** are under a field.
  You **won't** be able to create links **from** them, however, you may link **to** them.
- **Orange portals** are *not* under a field, despite the looks.
  You can link **from and to** orange circled portals.

Note that there are double and triple fields too. (Smart-linking can boost your AP gain `:)`)
[image: linking]

Comment: Your statement "You can link from and to orange circled portals" is a little bit confusing. You should state it like this: "You can link between the orange portals and from them to the red portals". Of course it should be noted that, in your example there aren't any missing links between the orange portals.